# Managing server instance identity on EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2

I recently brought up a cluster on EC2, and I felt like I had to invent a lot of things.  I'm wondering what kinds of tools, patterns, ideas are out there for how to deal with this.

Some context:

I had 3 different kinds of servers, so first I created AMIs for each of them.  The first AMI had zookeeper, so step one in deploying the system was to get the zookeeper server running.

My script then made a note of the mapping between EC2's completely arbitrary and unpredictable hostnames, and the zookeeper server.

Then as I brought up new instances of the other 2 kinds of servers, the first thing I would do is ssh to the new server, and add the zookeeper server to its /etc/hosts file.  Then as the server software on each instance starts up, it can find zookeeper.

Obviously this is a problem that lots of people have to solve, and it probably works a little bit differently in different clouds.

Are there products that address this concept?  I was pretty surprised that EC2 didn't provide some kind of way to tie your own name to its name.

Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 2):

[How to do some service discovery on Amazon EC2](http://web.archive.org/web/20090122182233/http://blog.elastic-grid.com/2008/06/30/how-to-do-some-service-discovery-on-amazon-ec2/) seems to have some good options.

Comment: Pretty interesting.  I like the idea of scanning instances to see what security group they are in.  That can be leveraged in interesting ways, to achieve a sort of naming.  Thanks for the link!

Comment: I've replaced the dead link with a Wayback Machine link.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might want to look at http://puppetlabs.com/mcollective/introduction/ and the suite of tools from http://puppetlabs.com in general.

From the site:

> The Marionette Collective AKA MCollective is a framework to build server orchestration or parallel job execution systems.
>
> Primarily we’ll use it as a means of programmatic execution of Systems Administration actions on clusters of servers. In this regard we operate in the same space as tools like Func, Fabric or Capistrano.

I am fairly certain mcollective was built to solve exactly the problem you are trying to address. But, be forewarned, it's not a DNS-based solution, it's a method of addressing arbitrarily large and arbitrarily tagged groups of hosts.